# Limit Year Range

Tags: javascript

Actually I am working on an HRM System, and am using a Year Picker, I want to limit it to a year from 1900 to current year.The code I am using is below

```
    $('#txtinitialYear').datepicker({ yearRange: "1900:c" });
            ({

                viewMode: 'years',
                minViewMode: 'years',
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'yyyy',
            });




</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:-

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    viewMode: 'years',
    minViewMode: 'years',
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy',
    yearRange: "-100:+0", // last hundred years
});
```